# Data Handling and importing huge matrix data

Tags: import

I have a file with some $18000\times5009$ matrix with file size `1GB` . this is huge data i want to import this efficiently as well as do data handling with this huge data and some plotting too.Please help me out to import it efficiently because `Import[xy,"Table"]` takes a lot of time and uses all my available RAM.

Comment: Well what's your RAM?

Comment: Does [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7525782/565518) help?

Comment: Have you tried `ReadList[xy]`?

Comment: The first thing you should do is not store such large data in ascii form.

Comment: @Feyer I have 8 GB RAM